# Using jQuery plugin in react environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm using semantic react but looking for date picker, I came across this library. https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar

But how do I use that since it's not react based?

Comment: is your project created with create-react-app or manually from scratch ?

Comment: @monssef does it matter?

Comment: yes it does, otherwise $('#calendar').calendar(...) will throw undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

First install it using npm, import it into your component,
then you have to initialize it in your component using

```
$('#mycalendar').calendar('behavior name', argumentOne, argumentTwo);
```

then you can initialize it  in comonentDidMount life cycle method.
like so

```
componentDidMount(){
$('#mycalendar').calendar('behavior name', argumentOne, argumentTwo);
}
```

After that you can use the celender in your jsx.
here is the link which you can follow for more information
https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar

this is the jsbin like for more examplehttps://jsbin.com/hubanufuva/1/edit?html,css,js,output

this link will help you to know how to use jquery with react https://medium.com/@shuvohabib/using-jquery-in-react-component-the-refs-way-969de9aa651f

Comment: init twice? why?